# Old Testament Rules

Tags: discussion

Lots of questions are starting to come in about "why isn't this OT rule still followed?". I believe we need a definitive question and answer on this subject, possibly in the FAQs.

Comment: I feel I've answered this quite well [here](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/15/do-we-have-to-obey-the-laws-of-the-bible-if-so-what-laws/506#506) and [here](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/456/to-what-extent-does-the-law-of-moses-still-apply/494#494).

Comment: Yes, you have. I'll be making some links to this answer.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to have a definitive answer on that question alone. I think we need a series of questions about how does tradition X handle OT rules. Asking from the perspective of a single rule is always going to garner a collection of answers based on the answerers POV and we're going to go round and round the same content until the sky falls.